# How to make a form submission to email using node and express

Tags: node.js, forms, email, express

How to collect data from form (name, email, attachments) and submit them to my email  using express. I didn't find a comprehensive articles on this topic. I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm a front-end developer  but have small experience with node.

Comment: You can find some articles on the Internet ( http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/07/02/send-email-node-js-express/ ). Your question is too narrow for the scope of the website, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am considering you know how to submit form

To send any mail through node install popular module 'nodemailer'

1-install nodemailer module in your project directory

```
npm install nodemailer
```

2-come to the controller where you are handling form submit data on server

```
var express = require('express'),
nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/formProcess', function (req, res) {
    var data=req.body;

    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
       service: "Gmail", 
       auth: {
       user: "email@gmail.com",
       pass: "gmailPassword"
       }});

   smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
   from: "Sender Name <email@gmail.com>",
   to: "Receiver Name <receiver@email.com>", // receiver
   subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
   html: "here your data goes" // body (var data which we've declared)
    }, function(error, response){  //callback
         if(error){
           console.log(error);
        }else{
           console.log("Message sent: " + res.message);
       }

   smtpTransport.close(); 
    }); });
```